# Can I get my BTC back from a scam site?

Tags: fraud

I invested Bitcoin in a fake site that was named as mega bit chain on the 6th of December. After that, I opened the site on the 12th of December; there was written: site is in maintenance. After two days the site was gone. Can I get my Bitcoin back?

Answer (score 3):

If the website does not send them back to you, there is no way of getting your Bitcoins back. You may be able to sue them, but I am no legal advice. There is no authority that can reimburse you or transfer them to the scam website back to you.